# What's the difference between "trust" and "believe"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

What's the difference between *trust* and *believe*? In a sentence such as

> Don't ... a man who keeps flattering you.

should I fill in *trust* or *believe*?

Comment: Either word fits, but the meaning is different.  After looking both words up in the dictionary what questions do you have about the difference between these words?

Comment: But the right answer is "trust" in the examing paper.I just want to know why?

Comment: The exam paper has arbitrarily picked an answer.  Unless they have provided context to push it one way, there is absolutely nothing wrong with *believe*.  In fact I'd probably choose it over *trust* because when they keep flattering you it's likely that they are saying things they think you want to hear instead of truths.  So I would first *not believe them* and then because I don't believe them I would not trust them.  But *trust* here is a secondary decision deriving from the disbelief.

Comment: I suppose though, as far as advice goes, advice is meant to help you, and clearly establishing trust is more helpful than simply establishing truth.

Comment: @Jim: I believe you have missed an inference. To simply not believe flattery is to disbelieve the flattering statements. The sentence given, as I see it, intends a stronger statement of not believing *anything* said by a flatterer, and thus not *trusting* them. From that analysis I believe *trust* is clearly the correct answer .

Comment: @PieterGeerkens- I believe you missed the second half of my comment above.

Comment: @Jim Writing "I trust you missed the second half of my comment above." would also have been acceptable.

Comment: "Trust" implies that a degree of faith is involved.

Answer (score 4):

**Trust** is a feeling or a general sense. It has to do with the way you perceive another person or source of information. If you trust someone you tend to *believe* that what they say is true. If you trust a certain website that means you think most if not all of the stories posted there are correct.

**Believe** has to do with individual facts, and its is on a case by case basis. Someone might say I believe that Syria used chemical weapons, but I don't believe the president knew about it.

Comment: I agree with this answer, in OP's context, with the proviso that 'belief' can also be a feeling (though not as strong an affiliation to the target as 'trust' is). Ardent religious beliefs for instance.

Answer (score 1):

BELIEVE : If someone gives you an information and find out that the information is true, then you will believe.

TRUST : If someone gives you an information and you accept it without finding out, it's means you trust the person

Comment: Not entirely true.  Many people believe received information without finding out that it is true.  Belief means that they accept it to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Trust presupposes Truth and precedes Belief!

Belief is to accept something as being TRUE...

Comment: Though this answer may be entirely correct, it is currently unsupported by any cited authority and reads as if it were simply one person's opinion. At English Language & Usage we try to provide stronger evidence than that in support of our answers, if we have it. Please consider adding authoritative corroboration to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you use *believe* it should be *never believe 'in' a man*, while *trust* does not need *in* after the word in this context.

Although both can be used interchangeably, in this context it would be *trust*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your posts will be easier for others to read and understand if you use the [mark down](http://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help) appropriately.

Comment: -1. You can believe a person just as much as you can believe _in_ a person. They mean two completely different things.